# Timer in HTML button (as a resend button to submit form)

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter-4

I'm sorry if I have bad in english. I hope you can understand what I mean.

Okay, as simply, I'm going to create a resend button with timer.

This button will be a resend button to submit form. If user access the page, the button doesn't start the timer. When user fill the form and submit it, the timer start running, change the text of button like "You can send after {numofsec} second", and add "disabled" class.

When it reach 0 sec, the button will remove "disabled" class and user could resubmit form.
My problem: This button always run timer when user access the page.

Here it is my code:

```
  let x;
  let sec = localStorage.getItem("sec") ? parseInt(localStorage.getItem("sec")) : 10;
  let interval = null;

  function timer() {
    localStorage.setItem("sec", sec);
    if (sec > 0) {
      localStorage.setItem("timer_status", "started")
      $("#btn_resend").prop('disabled', true)
      $("#btn_resend").html("Please wait for "+sec+" second");
      sec--
    } else if (sec === 0) {
      localStorage.clear()
      localStorage.setItem("timer_status", "stopped")
      sec = 10;
      $("#btn_resend").prop('disabled', false)
      $("#btn_resend").html("Resend");
      window.clearInterval(interval)
    }
  }

  window.onload = function () {
    <?php if (session()->get("timer_status") == "started") { ?>
    x = "started"
    localStorage.setItem("timer_status", "started");
    <?php } else if (session()->get("timer_status") == "stopped") { ?>
    x = "stopped"
    <?php } ?>
    
    if (x === "started") {
      interval = window.setInterval(timer, 1000);
    } else {
      window.clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }
```

There is a session that sent from Controller. I'm using **CodeIgniter 4**.

```
session()->set("timer_status", "started");
```

My problem: This button always run timer when user access the page.

I have already tried and I got confused for this logic.
I'm new at javascript language. Hope you all can help this problem. Thankyou.

Comment: Starting the timer on page load appears to be based on your `timer_status` in the server-side session. You set a bit of information in the client-side localStorage to keep track of the timer status in there, but I don’t see any code that would actually change the status in the server-side session. So where does _that_ happen? Does it happen at all?

Comment: @CBroe I forgot to set back the server-side session (to "stopped"). Problem was solved. Thankyou for your response.